# R-Shiny UI idiom for multi-select input with number pair

Tags: r, shiny

I need to allow the user to select some widgets from a fixed set of widgets and then enter a quantity for each widget he has selected.

```
selectInput("widgets","Widgets",choices = widgets_list,multiple = TRUE)
```

How can I show a set of Numeric Entry boxes dynamically, one for each item selected by the user in the multi-select box above?

Eventually I want to end up with some structure like:

```
data.frame(widgets=c("Widget1","Widget2","Widget3"),quantities=c(23,34,23))
```

Any thoughts on how best to implement this?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a toy program that does what you want - I think.

It uses a `reactiveValues` to declare a pair of vectors that you can then be changed reactively. It uses `renderUI` and `uiOutput` to render new input devices as the underlying data changes. It also uses `renderDataTable` to show you the data table that is being created.

```
library(shiny)    
widgets_list = c("Widget1","Widget2","Widget3")
widgets_quan = c(23,34,23)
u <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Shiny Widgets Input"),
  sidebarLayout(position = "left",
           sidebarPanel(h3("sidebar panel"),
                         uiOutput("widgname"),
                         uiOutput("widgquan")
                       ),
           mainPanel(h3("main panel"),
                     dataTableOutput("dataframe")
                     )
)))
s <- shinyServer(function(input,output) {

  rv <- reactiveValues(wname = widgets_list,wquan = widgets_quan)

  observeEvent(input$widgquan, {
      rv$wquan[ which(rv$wname==input$widget) ] <- input$widgquan
  })
  output$widgname <- renderUI({
    selectInput("widget","Widget",choices = rv$wname)
  })
  output$widgquan <- renderUI({
       req(input$widget)
       n <- rv$wquan[which(rv$wname == input$widget)]
       numericInput("widgquan","Quantity:",n)
  })
  widgdata <- reactive({
    req(input$widgquan)
    df <- data.frame(Widgets = rv$wname,Quantity = rv$wquan)
  })
  output$dataframe <- renderDataTable({ widgdata() })
})
shinyApp(ui = u,server = s)
```

yielding:
[image]

Comment: Thanks! Maybe I wasn't clear enough about my use case: Let me try again. There's a fixed large list of all widget names. Any particular user may want to select (say) two or three (or some number) widgets from this list. Once he does that I want to generate a set of matching input boxes that allow him to type in the quantities of those particular two or three etc. widget names that he has selected. I don't think your solution does that, right?